# Are questions about teaching literature on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

The site's current description on Area 51 says,

> Q&A site for scholars and enthusiasts of literature

This is a broad description, but just to be sure, I would like to know whether questions about teaching literature would be on topic. I have not seen any questions about this so far and I think it is an area that might attract more users.

Answer (score 6):

We haven't had any so far, nor have we had any meta discussions about them. So **go for it!** Try asking a question or two in this area, and see how they're received. If they get closed, we'll be back here on meta.

Note that we've already had questions about [physical-books](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical-books) and [library-and-information-science](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/library-and-information-science), which haven't been closed as off-topic. Our scope seems to be shaping up to be very broad on anything to do with books or written material, regardless of whether or not it's to do with the actual content.